# Research - Streaming results while a query is still running

Tags: sql, ajax, database

for a scientific project I am researching possibilities to improve the user experience when it comes to long-running queries in web applications. I want to have a look at how one can make the backend of an application more transparent to the user. To do that, I want to conduct some end-user research on live-returns or streaming of query results while the query is still running.

**Example:**

> A user wants to have a table of all invoices between the years 2010
>   and 2013 whose net value was between X and Y. The data should be displayed on some kind of web-
>   application

The idea is, that the user can see the result table grow on his web application as more and more results are being returned by the query.

**My question is:**

Is anybody aware of a database system that is able to stream or live-return query results while the query is still running? Or maybe somebody knows about some research, article or paper about this subject?

I already did quite some Google search, but unfortunately I could only find false-positives.

This is the only somehow related link I could find:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ebean/Q-oV-Ioio78

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: You mean like this: http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/large-scale-data-transfer-data-services-streaming/ or this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528818.aspx or did you really mean directly from the database to a client not going through N-Tier?

Comment: "While the query is still running" sounds like directly from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the links, unfortunately they are not quite what I mean with "live-streaming". I am looking for a way to provide "intermediate" results of a running query to the user. The links describe an approach to stream data from some middleware to the web server. In this scenario, the database server whould have had to finish the query before sending anything - which will then be streamed by some middleware. Actually, I am looking for some technique where the database itself can kind of "yield return" or stream results as soon as they fall out of the query processor or join engine.